# Activate the Rewrite mode in my remote server

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I just make my website in localhost. During the design and I enabled rewrite mode. 
However while hosting how to activate rewrite mode?

Without it enabled me return an error like 'Internal server error'.

Comment: Did you search for any information before asking this question? If you did, what information have you read that didn't answer what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hosting options, there are 2 ways:

1. For VPS/Dedicated hosting, you can edit the apache's .conf files.
2. For Shared hosting, enable the mod_rewrite in .htaccess file. Most hosters allows this.

.htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thank you .Now what the content of the .htaccess file?

Comment: What should be the content of the .htaccess file to enable reewrite mode?

Comment: Also, you need to speak with your hoster if he has enabled `mod_rewrite` on the machine. In most cases it's enabled but it doesn't hurt to ask to be sure.